# Doubts on Index mechanism of postgres database

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance, database-indexes

Definition of the `employees` table is as follow

```
                         Table "public.employees"
    Column     |          Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 employee_id   | integer                 |           | not null | 
 first_name    | character varying(1000) |           | not null | 
 last_name     | character varying(1000) |           | not null | 
 date_of_birth | date                    |           | not null | 
 phone_number  | character varying(1000) |           | not null | 
 subsidiary_id | integer                 |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "employee_pk" UNIQUE, btree (employee_id, subsidiary_id)
```

Content of the `employees` table is as follow

```
 employee_id | first_name | last_name | date_of_birth | phone_number | subsidiary_id 
-------------+------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+---------------
         120 | Ajay       | Yadav     | 2019-09-04    | 1232323      |             1
         129 | Rohit      | Gupta     | 2019-09-04    | 1232323      |             1
         123 | Vikash     | Sharma    | 2019-09-04    | 1232323      |             2
         130 | Jay        | Sharma    | 2019-09-05    | 1232323      |             3
         131 | Jay        | Sharma    | 2019-09-05    | 1232323      |             2
         134 | Jay        | Sharma    | 2019-09-05    | 1232323      |             3
(6 rows)
```

Checked the execution plan for the select query with employee id as the condition.

```
                         QUERY PLAN                         
------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on employees  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=1 width=1560)
   Filter: (employee_id = 123)
(2 rows)
```

The execution plan is showing that the query engine hasn't used the index and did a table scan operation.

The index contains employee Id as the first parameter then why database haven't used the index ?

Comment: For a table with just 6 rows, an index access isn't efficient

Comment: You have six rows in the table.  It doesn't matter how Postgres executes the query.

Comment: What is the query and secondly index will be used if there are sufficient rows .